# Uniform convergence of compactly supported function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

If $f\in C_c^\infty$, i.e. Compactly supported, then for $g_k(x)=f(kx)$, would $g_k\to 0$ uniformly as $k\to \infty$ since g vanishes outside a given compact set which won't be touched for $k$ arbitrarily large?

Comment: What if $f(0)\neq 0?$

Comment: You always have $\|g_k\|_\infty = \|f\|_\infty$. Thus, the convergence is uniform if and only if $f=0$.